# I am using Spring and MyBatis for my demo project for learning MyBatis Framework. I am repeatedly getting CLASS NOT FOUND Exception

Tags: eclipse, rest, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, mybatis

I am getting Class not Found Exception Repeatedly.

```
Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error registering typeAlias for 'Emp'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: classpath*:com.attinad.model.Employee
```

My myBatis-config.xml file is given below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

 <configuration>
  <typeAliases><typeAlias type="classpath*:com.attinad.model.Employee" alias="Emp"/></typeAliases>

 <mappers>
        <mapper resource="classpath:com/attinad/mappers/EmployeeMapper.xml" />
 </mappers>

</configuration>
```

And the ds-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
 <beans >
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/corpds"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     </bean>

            <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />             
            <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="classpath*:com/attinad/model/*"/>        
            <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:myBatis-config.xml" />
            <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/attinad/mappers/*.xml" />
     </bean>

</beans>
```

My mapper file EmployeeMapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">


<mapper namespace="com.attinad.dao.EmployeeMapperInterface">
<resultMap type="Emp" id="EmpResult">
    <id property="id" column="id"/>
    <result property="createdAt" column="createdAt"/>
    <result property="department" column="department"/>
    <result property="displayName" column="displayName"/>
    <result property="emailId" column="emailId"/>
    <result property="isEnable" column="isEnable"/>
    <result property="name" column="name"/>
    <result property="updatedAt" column="updatedAt"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getEmployeeWithId" parameterType="Long" resultMap="EmpResult"> 
        select *  from
        employees where
        id=#{empId}

    </select>
</mapper>
```

This is my dao class:

```
package com.attinad.dao;

import java.util.*;
import com.attinad.model.*;
public interface EmployeeMapperInterface extends BaseMapperInterface{
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeWithId(long id);
    public int insertEmployee(Employee e);
    public int updateEmployee(Employee e);
    public void deleteEmployee(int id);

}
```

And my service class:

```
package com.attinad.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.attinad.dao.EmployeeMapperInterface;
import com.attinad.model.Employee;


    @Service
    public class EmployeeService implements EmployeeBaseService{

        @Autowired
        EmployeeMapperInterface employeeMapper;

         @Override    
         public Employee getEmployeeById(long empId){

            List<Employee> empList = employeeMapper.getEmployeeWithId(empId);
            if(empList != null && empList.size()>0){
                //System.out.println("List accumulated");
                System.out.println(empList);
                return (Employee) empList.get(0);

            }
            return null;

        }
}
```

Eclipse build path:src/main/java is included in the Java Build Path and my packages are under this classpath.

Please help me with this error. I can't figure out the actual cause. When I removed the resultMap and made it ResultType="hashMap", it worked. But now if I try doing that, I am getting ClassNotFound for other classes.

Comment: What is the "Emp" class? And shouldn't you be using the canonical name?

Comment: I have used the alias name Emp and it is configured in the ds-config.xml file. <typeAliases><typeAlias type="classpath*:com.attinad.model.Employee" alias="Emp"/></typeAliases>

Comment: Well that's clearly not working, the way you think it should.

Comment: If I remove the Alias name and specify the fully qualified name for the type when writing resultMap, I am getting ClassNotFound Exception for "com.attinad.model.Employee". Can you please tell me the right way to do this?

Comment: @MikkelLøkke:" And shouldn't you be using the canonical name?"  I tried with canonical name also. Since it is not working, I changed it. But that too doesn't help.

Comment: Well, are you sure that `com.attinad.model.Employee` is actually on the Classpath? How are you building it?

Comment: @MikkelLøkke: Yes I am sure that it is in classpath.(the path:src/main/java is included in the Java Build Path and my packages are under this classpath.) Actually the code worked once When I removed the resultMap and made it resultType="hashMap". But when I try that now, its throwing ClassNotFoundException for my EmployeeMapperInterface and other classes.

Comment: I am building and deploying it to Tomcat through Eclipse IDE .

Comment: @MikkelLøkke :Any Updates on this? I am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very explicitly says that classloader tries to load class with name `classpath*:com.attinad.model.Employee`.

typeAliases configuration should look like:

```
<typeAliases><typeAlias type="com.attinad.model.Employee" alias="Emp"/></typeAliases>
```

**Note**: `classpath*:` is removed.

The same problem is with `sqlSessionFactory` bean configuration. `typeAliasPackage` should be specified like this:

```
<property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.attinad.model"/>
```

Comment: Initially I tried with type="com.attinad.model.Employee". And I got the error "Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error registering typeAlias for 'Emp'. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: com.attinad.model.Employee" That is When I tried attaching "classpath*:"

Comment: I've updated the answer. There is another similar problem in sqlSessionFactory bean configuration.

Comment: Do you have Employee class in that package? How do you execute query in mybatis? If you do Class.forName("com.attinad.model.Employee") before executing query does it find the class?

Comment: Yes I do have Employee class in that package. import com.attinad.model.Employee; works well. The query is written in an XML file and mapped to a function(See EmployeeMapper.xml above)and it is executed by the dao class' function.

Comment: When I asked about how you execute query I mainly interested whether you use mapper interface or session directly? Can you show the code?

Comment: I have updated my dao and service class. I am using my Mapper Interface.

Comment: :Any Updates on this? I am still getting the same problem

Comment: As I wrote in answer configuration of type aliases is not correct in both mybatis conf and in spring conf. Have you fixed this? What error do you get with correct configuration?

Comment: Yes I have tried after removing the "classpath:"(that was my intial config. I added it after getting classpath error). I still get the same error.

Comment: You can't get exactly same error if you did change both configuration files. It may be similar but still different. In any case current question mentions incorrect configuration and error messages based on it.